# Foreach, insert multiple colums in LINQ from list

Tags: c#, linq

So i have a table `LNK_USER_ROLE` in which i assign users to respective role ids.

In this case, i try to assign both the "ADMIN" and "USER" role to the user. Therefore i query the id's of the roles, from my role table so that i can add them into my `LNK_USER_ROLE` table along with the user id. (The `LNK_USER_ROLE` `ROLE_ID` is a foreign key to `ID` in the `ROLE` db)

```
var db = new MySqlContext();

List<int> RoleId = db.ROLES.Where(u => u.ROLE_NAME == "ADMIN" && u.ROLE_NAME == "USER").Select(u => u.ROLE_ID).ToList();


        foreach(int id in RoleId)
        {
            LNK_USER_ROLE Roles = new LNK_USER_ROLE();
            {
               Roles.ROLE_ID = id;
               Roles.USER_ID = db.USERS.Where(u => u.EMAIL == model.Users.EMAIL && u.NAME == model.Users.NAME).Select(u => u.USER_ID).Single();
            };

       db.LNK_USER_ROLE.Add(Roles);
       }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens! As you can see, i should most likely have 2 rows added in my table if this code was successful.. I however don't know how i should use the `Foreach` to insert rows, and i cant seem to find previous questions that match my need.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step to see what is happening?

Comment: I think you might need to change your where statement slightly to use || (Or) instead of && (And), when selecting role ids. i.e. `.Where(u => u.ROLE_NAME == "ADMIN" || u.ROLE_NAME == "USER")`

Comment: But i want both Role names. Or would select just 1 of them?

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Your query at the moment will not work because its basically looking for records where role name equals both USER and ADMIN, which wont work. You want records which role name is either ADMIN or USER to select 2 records. (Based on the that role names are unique)

Comment: I guess you are correct. When i test my code, this actually also yields 0. But how would i do it then? im fairly new to the linq syntax

Comment: @JeppeChristensen Should be a case of replacing the && with || in the query. `.Where(u => u.ROLE_NAME == "ADMIN" || u.ROLE_NAME == "USER")`

Comment: That actually works,!

Comment: JeppeChristensen really, just do what @Valeklosse is telling you. And then, go and read a bit about boolean algebra and logical operators :)

Comment: I will sir! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the And (`&&`) and Or (`||`) operator.

The query is trying to select records where the ROLE_NAME is equal to 'ADMIN' and 'USER' at the same time.

Changing the query from

`List<int> RoleId = db.ROLES.Where(u => u.ROLE_NAME == "ADMIN" && u.ROLE_NAME == "USER").Select(u => u.ROLE_ID).ToList();`

to

`List<int> RoleId = db.ROLES.Where(u => u.ROLE_NAME == "ADMIN" || u.ROLE_NAME == "USER").Select(u => u.ROLE_ID).ToList();`

Will result in selecting records where ROLE NAME is equal to 'ADMIN' or 'USER'

Example:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xju2Wo